# check for null values on Data Flow Azure Data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Imagine I have following four rows on a SQL database:

| id | county | city | adress | price | datefrom | dateto | iscurrent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | PT | Lisbon | jack | 10000 | 2012-1-1 | 2022-1-10 | 0 |
| 3 | PT | Lisbon | jack | 10000 | 2012-8-1 | null | 1 |
| 4 | ES | Madrid | ola str | 23000 | 2022-3-1 | 2022-3-10 | 0 |
| 4 | ES | Madrid | ola str | 23000 | 2022-10-1 | 2023-1-01 | 0 |

I want to create a date flow on azure data factory that checks if the inactive rows (iscurrent =0) have a duplicate row (of the first 5 columns from id to price) that is active (iscurrent =1).

To do that I create an Aggregate transformation, I group by ID,COUNTRY,ADRESS,PRICE. My problem is which kind of expression should I use under aggregation to create a new column (havenulls) that shows 1 if there is null values on dateto, or 0 if there is no values. The output should be:

| id | county | city | adress | price | datefrom | havevulls |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | PT | Lisbon | jack | 10000 | 2012-1-1 | 1 |
| 4 | ES | Madrid | ola str | 23000 | 2022-10-1 | 0 |

If I manage to get this or similar output I can thereafter split between "duplicates" that are active or not.

If you guys know another way to get the same result I am eager to hear from you.

thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the assert activity that you are looking for:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-assert

You can check for duplicate or null as well.